# What is the best way to determine the time it takes a service to return?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, rosservice, rostime

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am using ROS Melodic on Ubuntu 18.04

Is there some ROS function that returns the execution duration of a ROS service?

Or is the easiest way to get the execution duration to `ros::Time::now()` before and after the service is called and then finding the difference?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/355112/what-is-the-best-way-to-determine-the-time-it-takes-a-service-to-return?/) by [marcp17](https://answers.ros.org/users/52300/marcp17/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2020-06-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Is there some ROS function that returns the execution duration of a ROS service?

Not that I know of (as in: *this* specifically).

> Or is the easiest way to get the execution duration to `ros::Time::now()` before and after the service is called and then finding the difference?

That could certainly work.

Another approach would be to use a profiler, perhaps something like [swri-robotics/swri_profiler](https://github.com/swri-robotics/swri_profiler) (but there are of course more).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [marcp17](https://answers.ros.org/users/52300/marcp17/) on 2020-06-17**:
Thanks for the reply. I will have a look at profilers